# JavaScript/ HTML video tag in Safari. Block now playing controls

Tags: javascript, safari, video-streaming, html5-video

I am looking for a way to disable now playing controls for html video in Safari. The controls that let you skip / rewind / pause / play from the iOS or Mac.

Background. I work at a school. I need to block skipping ahead for the students. In my web interface that is fine because I can only give them the playback controls I want them to have. However the OS controls still let the students skip forward.

I know it’s possible because YouTube does this.

Comment: The YouTube comment is interesting!